# How to create libpgm discrete bayesian network CPD/data file from raw data

Tags: python, bayesian-networks

I am trying to create a Bayesian network using libpgm library in python. The  documentation (http://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/#documentation) provides details of how to use the library given the network structure and parameters are already learnt. However I am unable to figure out how to create the input dictionary for the network as given here (http://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/unittestdict.html) . Current I have only the raw data in the format of variables and observations. What approach should I take to find the network structure and parameters automatically?
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

use the pgmlearner to automatically retrieve the data you are looking for https://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/pgmlearner.html